# Storing PDF from NSData to iphone phone library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a pdf where the content is coming from NSData retrieved from webservice. I am trying to save this data as a pdf in the device photo library. Is it possible to store this as pdf in phone library or I will have to convert it to an image and then save it?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(viewFrame1.frame.size);
[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```

Comment: hayden, thanks for the answer. I notice the only way to land the pdf is to safe it as an image I believe.

Answer (score -1):

To retrieve the Library Path:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *libraryDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

responseData is the NSData object you have with the pdf information. This will save the pdf as "mypdffile.pdf" in your applications Library folder.

```
[responseData writeToFile:[libraryDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"mypdffile.pdf"] atomically:YES];
```

I found this page very useful.
[Working with Files in Objective-C](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Working_with_Files_in_Objective-C)

Comment: Yes, it writes but Preview.app is not able to open the file saved in this way. Any help?